# Jquery mobile HTML5 application online & oflline issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing one Iphone application using jquery mobile + HTML5. I can check the app offline & online status. I have an google map to show the location of the user. Now the problem is whenever app is online i can be able to show the google map. When app goes offline, i hides the google map & shows the offline message. 
Now when mobile gets internet connection, i can get the online status, but cant be able to reload the google map js & object. It gives me an error.

So how to refresh the DOM whenever the device get internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JQM (ajax page transition) when ever i go to the page the 'Pagebeforeshow' & 'pageshow' events get fired. So i have added the connection check

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
    isOnline = true;
    return true;
} else {

    isOnline = false;
    localStorage.setItem('offlineCount', '1');
    return true;
}
```

So the issue get resolved. But it still remain about how to refresh DOM using Jquery after ajax requests.